# Agile Development Contract Template - Time and Materials with Variable Scope and Cost Ceiling

Tags: agile

Peter Stevens has a great summary of different agile contract models on his blog.  I've decided that I like one of them the best ([Time and Materials with Variable Scope and Cost Ceiling](http://agilesoftwaredevelopment.com/blog/peterstev/10-agile-contracts#TAM-vscc)) for a project I'm initiating, but I can't find a sample contract or template for such a contract.  Anyone know where I could find something like that?

Comment: See also http://alistair.cockburn.us/Agile+contracts

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because project management is off-topic. Such questions should be asked at [https://pm.stackexchange.com/](https://pm.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Jeff Sutherland (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Sutherland) spoke at Agile 2008 on this topic: http://jeffsutherland.com/scrum/2008/08/agile-2008-money-for-nothing.html (slides: http://jeffsutherland.com/scrum/Agile2008MoneyforNothing.pdf)

It spawned an "Agile Contracts" discussion over here: http://www.coactivate.org/projects/agile-contracts/summary, and that discussion includes a wiki page that's the beginnings of a contract template: http://www.coactivate.org/projects/agile-contracts/money-for-nothing-change-for-free

Answer (score 2):

Not a template, but some additional tips that might help with this - from Mike Cohn:

http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/articles/5-writing-contracts-for-agile-development

Comment: I don't think this answered what he was asking also... more like how to write a better user stories...

Answer (score -2):

[rewritten in response to comment on original post]

It's not so difficult to write, examples can be found in your native tongue all over the Internet (plain time-material contract to start from). Just make sure you keep it clear and simple.

The 2 things to remember are:

1. Write in your native language, to prevent confusion (if client is abroad English is best). E.g. our contracts are stated in Dutch.
2. Have your attorney check whatever you come up with, for a decent template

Comment: Your answer does not provide any value. Please write the template if it's not that difficult or ask one of your customers for us and I will be happy to give you an up-vote.